# Tablet pen doesn't work correctly when in portrait mode

Tags: 11.04, lenovo, tablet, stylus

I'm using a lenovo x201 tablet. I recently upgraded to 11.04. When I rotate the screen 90 degrees (in either direction) to use the computer in portrait mode, the tablet pen does not work correctly. More specifically, the action of the tablet pen is reflected in the horizontal center line. Does anyone know how to correct this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using magick-rotation?  I just fixed the same problem.

Here's the way to update the wacom driver that could be responsible for that mess :

https://answers.launchpad.net/magick-rotation/+faq/1603